# How to properly configure the USART_BRR register in STM32L476RG uC?

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, stm32, bare-metal

I'm trying to write my own driver for USART_TX on an STM32L476RG Nucleo Board.
Here the [datasheet](https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32l476rg.html) and the [reference manual](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/02/35/09/0c/4f/f7/40/03/DM00083560.pdf/files/DM00083560.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00083560.pdf).

I'm using Keil uVision 5 and I set in the Manage dialog:

- CMSIS > Core
- Device > Startup
- **Xtal=16MHz**

I want to create a single character transmitter. According to the manual instructions in Sec. 40 p 1332 I wrote this code:

```
// APB1 connects USART2
// The USART2 EN bit on APB1ENR1 is the 17th
// See alternate functions pins and label for USART2_TX! PA2 is the pin and AF7 (AFRL register) is the function to be set


#include "stm32l4xx.h"                  // Device header

#define MASK(x) ((uint32_t) (1<<(x)));

void USART2_Init(void);
void USART2_Wr(int ch);
void delayMs(int delay);

int main(void){
    USART2_Init();
    

    while(1){
    USART2_Wr('A');
    delayMs(100);
        
        
    }
}

void USART2_Init(void){
    RCC->APB1ENR1 |= MASK(17); // Enable USART2 on APB1
    // we know that the pin that permits the USART2_TX is the PA2, so...
    RCC->AHB2ENR |= MASK(0); // enable GPIOA
    
    // Now, in GPIOA 2 put the AF7, which can be set by placing AF7=0111 in AFSEL2 (pin2 selected)
    // AFR[0] refers to GPIOA_AFRL register
    // Remember: each pin asks for 4 bits to define the alternate functions. see pg. 87 
    // of the datasheet
    GPIOA->AFR[0] |= 0x700; 
    GPIOA->MODER &= ~MASK(4);// now ... we set the PA2 directly with moder as alternate function "10"
    
    // USART Features -----------
    
    //USART2->CR1 |=MASK(15); //OVER8=1
    USART2->BRR = 0x683; //USARTDIV=16Mhz/9600?
    //USART2->BRR = 0x1A1; //This one works!!!
    USART2->CR1 |=MASK(0); //UE
    USART2->CR1 |=MASK(3); //TE
    
}

void USART2_Wr(int ch){
    //wait when TX buffer is empty
    while(!(USART2->ISR & 0x80)) {} //when data is transfered in the register the ISR goes 0x80.
        //then we lock the procedure in a while loop until it happens
        USART2->TDR =(ch & 0xFF); 

}

void delayMs(int delay){
int i;
    for (; delay>0; delay--){
        for (i=0; i<3195; i++);
    }
}
```

Now, the problem:

The system works, but not properly. I mean: if I use RealTerm at 9600 baud-rate, as configured by 0x683 in USART_BRR reg, it shows me wrong char but *if I set 2400 as baud rate on real term it works!*

To extract the 0x683 in USART_BRR reg i referred to **Sec. 40.5.4 USART baud rate generation** and it says that if OVER8=0 the USARTDIV=BRR. In my case, USARTDIV=16MHz/9600=1667d=683h.

I think that the problem lies in this code row:

```
USART2->BRR = 0x683; //USARTDIV=16Mhz/9600?
```

because if I replace it as

```
USART2->BRR = 0x1A1; //USARTDIV=16Mhz/9600?
```

THe system works at 9600 baud rate.

What's wrong in my code or in the USARTDIV computation understanding?

Thank you in advance for your support.

Sincerely,
GM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default clock source for the USART is `PCLK1` (figure 15)  `PCLK1` is `SYSCLK / AHB_PRESC / AHB1_PRESC`.  If `0x1A1` results in a baud rate of 9600, that suggests `PCLK1` = 4MHz.

4MHz happens to be the default frequency of your processor (and `PCLK1`) at start-up when running from the internal MSI RC oscillator.  So the most likely explanation is that you have not configured the clock tree, and are not running from the 16MHz HSE as you believe.

Either configure your clock tree to use the 16MHz source, or perform your calculations on the MSI frequency. The MSI precision is just about good enough over normal temperature range to maintain a sufficiently accurate baud rate, but it is not ideal.

Comment: https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/training/technical/product_training/7c/c6/36/09/9f/21/44/9c/STM32L4_System_RCC.pdf/files/STM32L4_System_RCC.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.STM32L4_System_RCC.pdf

Thank you. I find something about your answer here.

Comment: @g.mezzina23 in most cases the clocks are configured in the C runtime startup code.